# Different return type of generic method depending on invocation location

Tags: java, generics

I have the following method with generics that executes the getter of each item in the list it receives:

```
public static <T, S> List<S> getValues(List<T> list, String fieldName) {
    List<S> ret = new ArrayList<S>();
    String methodName = "get" + fieldName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
            + fieldName.substring(1, fieldName.length());
    try {
        if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
            for (T t : list) {
                ret.add((S) t.getClass().getMethod(methodName).invoke(t));
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It works perfectly fine if I call it as this:

```
List<Integer> ids = getValues(List<MyDTO>, "id");
request.setListIds(ids);
```

But, it gives me a compile error if I do it in a single line:

```
request.setListIds(getValues(List<MyDTO>, "id"));
```

The error says:

> The method setListIds(List-Integer-) in the type
>   MyDTO is not applicable for the arguments
>   (List-Object-)

So, when I try to directly set the list, it is casting the generic to Object instead of Integer. Why is that?

Comment: This method isn't type safe. The caller can give whatever type argument it wants for `S` and there's no guarantee that `invoke` will return a compatible type of object. Worse, the cast to `S` is *unchecked*, meaning it will not fail fast if wrong. Instead, the method should take a `Class<S>` and then use [`cast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast\(java.lang.Object\)) rather than `(S)`. Incidentally that would also fix the type inference issue since the compiler could infer `S` from the specified `Class<S>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is due to Java's quite weak type inference. It can infer the type when you directly assign to a variable, but it won't infer by the target argument type, which you need in the second example.

You can overcome this with `this.<Integer>getValues...`

Comment: Basically +1, but: Catching `Exception` will also catch an exception like a `NullPointerException` that is not related to the other exceptions which should be caught and that points to a bug in the code. Of course, the OP should handle the exceptions properly. But he should use Java 7's multi-catch clause or catch the different exceptions in different blocks (as he does now) instead of catching `Exception`.

Comment: Great answer! About the Exceptions, I just deleted the exception handling to paste it here, but thanks.

Comment: @RobinKrahl Well, the *reallly* good idea is not to catch anything---but you are forced to catch checked ones. So what I would have in the handler is just a rethrow of the exception, wrapped if needed. BTW *any* exception in this point is as much a bug as an `NPE`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, that would be one possibility for proper handling.  But the thing that is important to my is not to catch *every* `Exception`, but only specified ones.

Comment: @RobinKrahl If you rethrow, you are not really catching---that's my point. And my second point is, since *any* exception is as much a bug as the checked ones, then what exactly is the point of carefully selecting just them?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the compiler is not correctly guessing the generic type variables. In the assigment, he correctly guesses `S=Integer`, while when passing the result as parameter, it is not taking into account the generic type of the method parameter.

This is because of type-erasure, since the signature of the method at runtime is `setListIds(List)`, not `setListIds(List<Integer>)`. By the way the same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651589/why-cant-javac-infer-generic-type-arguments-for-functions-used-as-arguments), and the answer explains why the compiler behaves like that.

Comment: This is not about type erasure. As you say yourself, it's a compile-time issue.

Answer (score 1):

No cast took place in the actual compiled bytecode of the method, because of [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when).

When generating bytecode, the compiler treats any variable of a parameter type as having the same type as that parameter type's upper bound, or `Object` if the type is unbounded.  So if `S` in your method had the constraint `<S extends Integer>`, the compiler would have inserted a cast to `Integer`.  However, as `S` is unbounded, any references to `S` are treated in the bytecode as being of type `Object` - thus, no cast.

With your method as written, you could get rid of the compile error by filling in the type parameters when invoking the method:

```
YourClass.<MyDTO, Integer>getValues(list, "id")
```

Though as this looks clunky, you'd probably do well to get rid of the type parameter `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method signature like:

```
public static <T, S> List<S> getValues(List<T> list, String fieldName, Class<S> fieldType) {
  //Your code goes here
}
```

Then following code will work seamlessly:

```
request.setListIds(getValues(List<MyDTO>, "id", Integer.class));
```