# Java Generics, define type during method call

Tags: java, android, generics, casting, type-conversion

I have two static methods:

```
  public static Selector<TextView, Property<String>> textView(
          final Selector<TextView, Property<TextView>> selector) {
    return null;
  }

  public static <V extends View> Selector<V, Property<V>> withId(final int id) {
    return null;
  }
```

Why Java compiler cannot resolve the required parameter type during the call???

```
textView(withId(R.id.et_password));
```

But easily accepts this:

```
Selector<TextView, Property<TextView>> p;
textView((p = withId(R.id.et_password));
```

Anybody can hint me how to trick the compiler?

P.S. `class TextView extends View { ... }`

Comment: does `View` extend `TextView`?

Comment: right, class TextView extends View { ... }

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply an explicit type parameter for this case. The syntax is:

```
textView(MainActivity.<TextView>withId(R.id.et_password));
```

assuming `MainActivity` is the class with these methods (it cannot be ommited, even when this code is inside the class).

In case `withId` was an instance method instead of a static one, then it would be:

```
textView(this.<TextView>withId(R.id.et_password));
```

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14652257/82788) for a good explanation of the reason. The difference in this particular case is that the erasure for `<V extends View> Selector<V, Property<V>>` is `Selector<View, Property<View>>` (and not `<Object>`, simply because `V` is known to extend `View`).

And as you can see, this is precisely the error the compiler shows:

> The method
>   `textView(Selector<TextView,Property<TextView>>)`
>   is not applicable for the arguments
>   `(Selector<View,Property<View>>)`